# Changing the default page of grails app results in 404 error

Tags: grails

I have a sample grails project and I wanted to change default home page and made changes accordingly to `UrlMappings.grrovy` file

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

//      "/"(view:"/index")
            "/"(controller: "LoginController", action:"/login")
    "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Problem is am getting 404 error with the index.gsp not found.

What I did was added a new controller which has action login and it gives me this error.
Am using `grails 2.2.4`.

Comment: drop the controller keyword from the controller. just use `"/"(controller: "login", action:"/login")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to map your home page:

```
"/"(controller: "login", action:"login")
```